# Integrating tomcat with lightttpd

Tags: java, tomcat, lighttpd

I just want to speed up the tomcat. For this reason I saw that lighttpd 
is able to run in front of tomcat processing static content

My application has this structure in tomcat server:

${tomcat_webapps}/lingoos/...

I just need to write a rule which forward the request for tomcat having 
this format:

1. /lingoos/customer/orders.jsp
2. /lingoos/customer/price.do
3. /lingoos/wicket/ssi?p=1&m=2

How can I tell to "mod-proxy" to forward to tomcat these 3 requests

I need to configure somehow this:

proxy.server               = ( "*.do" =>
                               ( "localhost" =>
                                 (
                                   "host" => "localhost",
                                   "port" => 8080
                                 )
                               )
                             )

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this other thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/53628/apache-lighttpd-for-load-balancing), you might want to consider using [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/).  Lighthttpd has had only 1 release in the past year, which seems to buttress the impression that its maintenance is slowing down.

Here is [another thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/293348/configure-nginx-for-jboss-tomcat) that gives full instructions for nginx-Tomcat integration.